# upgrade has caused page content to disappear

Tags: pages, content, upgrade

I've just transferred a site from one server to another and gone through it and tested it and made sure all the content was there etc etc. I then did a backup of the database via phpMyAdmin and did an export of the content within wordpress. I then downloaded the latest version of Wordpress and did a manual upgrade but overwriting all the wp-admin folder, the wp-includes folder, the core files etc - I didn't touch my theme or uploads or plugins folders.

I then did an upgrade of the database - all went well but when I returned to my site all is fine except the content on the pages - this is all missing when visiting the website, but when I go into the backend and view the pages to edit all the content is present - it's just not showing up on the live site.

Anyone knoe how I can fix this.

I've just realised I forgot to deactivate my plugins before upgrading - damn - would that cause the problem?

Comment: I just deactivated the plugins and tested the site - still no page content.

Comment: Did you change your domain name too?

Comment: I've also noticed that if I create new pages they can't be viewed. whether they are parent pages or sub pages if I publish them and then preview or click view page I get: Not Found - The requested URL /this-is-a-test-page/ was not found on this server. so I've got a major issue here. The client won't be creating any new parent pages, but may want to create child pages in the future.

Comment: the domain name remained the same. what's the domain name got to do with it?

Comment: now none of my pages are working at all apart from the homepage - argh! just getting the not found error on each page!

Comment: page links now working again for some reason. How do I get this site working again???

Comment: Just did an import of the wp xml that I created before upgrading - still no page content appearing on the website

Comment: I've fixed it! Or in the process of doing so - I'm having to update the old code within the page templates in order to get the content displayed - I can't remember which version of Wordpress was running before but it was pretty old.

Not tried creating a new page yet, but will try that next and see if that is still an issue. Might have to update the code within page.php

Comment: Nice one! I asked about the domain name as a common mistake (when moving between them) is to not swap out all the old instances in the database with the new one, which can cause all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If content displays within WordPress itself when you are logged into the dashboard but does not display on the front end of your site it is almost always a theme problem. If you have access to server logs, such as error logs in cPanel, you can see what errors are being thrown up.

The easy way to test if the theme is the problem is to change your theme to the default TwentyTen theme and see if your content appears.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah something similar has happened to me in the past after tweaking the wordpress loop. If you have on thing off usually it will display a blank page. I don't know if you did any editing of to any of your wp_query(s) after the move, but you might want to give them a second look.

I fixed my above issue by just taking out all of my loops and saving the theme. Then just going back through and reentering the code.